# Does pseudospin necessarily carry angular momentum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, quantum-spin, two-level-system

And if so, why?

I was told that anything that mathematically transforms like a spin must carry angular momentum. Is this true?

One example of pseudospin is electrons in graphene on the A and B lattice sites.

Comment: That’s not true at all, who told you that?

Answer (score 0):

The electron has a spin angular momentum of $\hbar/2$.

Pseudospin symmetry in graphene is related to graphene's orbital degeneracy.

It's similar to the "sea of electrons" in the $\pi$ orbitals of the benzene molecule - but much larger.

The mathematics of spin can be applied to any object which transforms under the $SU(2)$ Lie Algebra in a complex $2$ dimensional space regardless of whether or not it has physical spin.